# Dockerfile: How can I build my project before copying only the needed files to the image?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

```
FROM golang:1.8

RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y curl

RUN go get -u github.com/gorilla/mux

RUN go get github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | bash - && \
    apt-get install -y nodejs

COPY . /go/src/beginnerapp

WORKDIR ./src/beginnerapp/beginner-app-react

RUN npm run build

RUN go install beginnerapp/

WORKDIR /go/src/beginnerapp/beginner-app-react

VOLUME /go/src/beginnerapp/local-db

WORKDIR /go/src/beginnerapp

ENTRYPOINT /go/bin/beginnerapp

EXPOSE 8080
```

At the start, the golang project as well as the reactjs code don't exist on the image and need to be copied over before being able to build (js) / install (golang). Is there a way I can do that build/install process before copying files over to the image? Ideally I'd only need to copy over the golang executable and reactjs production build.

Comment: why do you want to build before copying the required folder?

Comment: build "go install" on image "FROM golang:1.8", then copy (only bins) to different image "FROM alpine"

Comment: @JinnaBalu I'd like a final image with only a single golang executable and production build of the reactjs folder to minimize container size. It seems that multi-stage builds are the way to go which I'll give a shot when I get the chance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is possible now using multi stage builds. The idea is that you can have multiple FROM in your docker file and your main image will be built using the last FROM. Below is a sample pseudo structure

```
FROM node:latest as reactbuild
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN webpack build

FROM golang:latest as gobuild
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN go build

FROM alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=gobuild /app/myapp /app/myapp
COPY --from=reactbuild /app/dist /app/dist
```

Please read below article for more details

https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/multistage-build/

Comment: I see `alpine` being used in examples quite often. Is that because it is the most lightweight image for a container? Are there other reasons?

Comment: Yes light and gives you a bit more functionality than a scratch image. You get basic unix commands